# Property losing values on form submit MVC3

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

This is a mvc3, Razor view engine, vb.net project. I am stuck at one spot and it more or less is an issue with never having to do something like this until now..

Basically the meat of the issue is that I have a view that can have 1 to many checkboxes in it depending on the amount of items listed in a table. The checkboxes will all use the name provided from that table as well.. Whatever checkboxes the user has checked will be saved in the controller when the model is passed back..

Everything is working correctly except when submitted.. I am losing the Bodies property of the model all together when the submit button is clicked..

```
@ModelType xxxxxx.CourseModel

@Code
ViewData("Title") = "Edit Courses"
End Code

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"  type="text/javascript"></script>


 @Using Html.BeginForm(Nothing, Nothing, FormMethod.Post, New With {.enctype = "multipart/form-data"})
 @Html.ValidationSummary(True)

    @<fieldset>
    <legend>Edit Courses</legend>
    @Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.cId)
    <table style="float: left">
    <tr>

     <th>Certification Bodies</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     @For _i As Integer = 0 To Model.Bodies.Count - 1
            Dim i = _i
            @<td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(Function(model) model.Bodies.ElementAt(i).certSelected)@Html.DisplayFor(Function(f) f.Bodies.ElementAt(i).certName)@Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.Bodies.ElementAt(i).certBodyId)</td>
        Next

    </tr>
    <tr><th><input type="submit" value="Save" /></th></tr>
    </table>
```

And the model currently is as follows:

```
    Public Class CourseModel
       Private _cId As Integer
       Public Property cId() As Integer
       Get
        Return _cId
       End Get
       Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _cId = value
       End Set
       End Property
       Private m_Bodies As New List(Of CertBodyVM)
    Public Property Bodies() As List(Of CertBodyVM)
    Get
        Return m_Bodies
    End Get
    Set(value As List(Of CertBodyVM))
        m_Bodies = value
    End Set
    End Property
    End Class
```

This is the CertBodyVM

```
Public Class CertBodyVM
Private _certName As String
Public Property certName() As String
    Get
        Return _certName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _certName = value
    End Set
End Property
Private _certSelected As Boolean
Public Property certSelected() As Boolean
    Get
        Return _certSelected
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        _certSelected = value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_certBodyId As Integer
Public Property certBodyId() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_certBodyId
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        m_certBodyId = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

Lastly the controller function that loads this view..

```
  Function EditCourse(ByVal id As Integer) As ViewResult

        Dim courses As New CourseModel
        Dim newCourse As cours = db.courses.Single(Function(c) c.course_id = id)

        courses.cId = newCourse.course_id

        courses.cRef = newCourse.course_ref

        Dim cBodies As List(Of certbody) = db.certbodies.Where(Function(F) F.confNum = _AnnualNumber AndAlso F.Display = 1).ToList
        For Each _cb In cBodies
            Dim cb = _cb
            Dim x As New CertBodyVM
            x.certBodyId = cb.idCertBodies
            x.certName = cb.CertBodyName
            Try
                Dim csetBodies As coursecertifybody = db.coursecertifybodies.Where(Function(f) f.cert_Body_id = cb.idCertBodies AndAlso f.course_ref = newCourse.course_ref AndAlso f.course_id = newCourse.course_id).FirstOrDefault
                If Not IsNothing(csetBodies) Then
                    x.certSelected = True
                Else
                    x.certSelected = False
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                x.certSelected = False
            End Try
            courses.Bodies.Add(x)
        Next

        Return View(courses)
    End Function
```

In the interest of SO standards I am including the post controller function below and since I can place a watch on the _eCourse var and see that bodies is empty there is no need for anything more than the below.

```
   <AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)>
    Function EditCourse(ByVal _eCourse As CourseModel) As ActionResult
     'Do something with _eCourse
    Return RedirectToAction("Blah")
    End Function
```

Any ideas why I am losing the Bodies property when the model is submitted???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model binding for a collection won't work with `.elementAt(i)`. Instead, try using this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(Function(model) model.Bodies[i].certSelected)
@Html.DisplayFor(Function(f) f.Bodies[i].certName)
@Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.Bodies[i].certBodyId)
```

Comment: indexes in vb.net use "(" ")" and not "[" "]" but other than that the solution is spot on.. Thanks much..